# Where to set environment variables for Ubuntu running on Vagrant?

Tags: php, heroku, vagrant, environment-variables, vagrantfile

I'm running a PHP app on Heroku, and I have no issues retrieving environment variables with the `heroku:config` command, but I need to have separate variables locally.

I'm vagrant ssh-ing into Ubuntu, but for the life of me can't figure out where to actually set the variables. I've tried using `~/.bashrc`, as well as putting the variables in the provisioning script, but I can't get the `$_ENV` (or `getenv()`) function in PHP to actually retrieve the variable. When I call those functions I am told that the variables are not set in the environment.

Any ideas how to set environment variables in the local environment for a PHP Heroku app?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it should work from `~/.bashrc` file but it might depend which bash you use.

You can put your env variables into the `.profile` for example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You would need to do that for the user that runs apache (if apache or nginx or any other web server you use)
Make sure to add those variables for the user that runs apache (if apache or nginx or any other web server you use), not your vagrant user.

The difference with Heroku is that your heroku user will own all your process including the web server so the variable you define can be accessed, with a standard ubuntu local (or vm-ized) the web server would be owned by root or a web user.

If you're not sure you can also place the variables inside `/etc/environment` and reference this file from `/etc/apache2/envvars` as :

```
# Load all the system environment variables.
. /etc/environment
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, I've tried using the `.bashrc` for enviroment variables, but the PHP `getenv()` function cannot retrieve variables from that.

Comment: @JakeByman guess you modified the `.bashrc` for your local user (or vagrant user) it must be done for the user owning apache process